# Trying so hard to Link to tabbed content from an external link

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, accordion

Terribly frustrated and embarrassed that I can't figure this out. Client wants a sitemap at the bottom of the website that takes the user to any page and any tab within that page with a single click.  Should be easy enough to do, but for some reason, I can't wrap my brain around it.  In the effort of complete honesty, I am an artist, with just enough code knowledge to be dangerous.  I can't write JQuery on my own, but I am able to read through already written things and understand what is going on, for the most part.

1. Example 1- Contact.php Possesses basic functionality
2. Example 2- TabTest1.html I was able to take the information from stackoverflow's .com questions 10616833/link-to-anchor-inside-tabbed-content-from-an-external-link and get it to work.  The script there actually doesn't work (for me).  Took me a day, but I figured out what it was (brackets, as usual) and what you see is that information at work. Unfortunately, it doesn't just plug into my already existing code. I've tried a couple of different ways, but I don't completely understand what is going on in the jsfiddle.
3. Example 2- ContactRE.php This is my best attempt to work with the code given in the above question.  I just feel overwhelmed. You can click on the tabs and see what it is doing, but after a click on any tab, they all light up as selected, but the content doesn't change at all.  I have a suspicion it has something to do with the "//return false;" before the "if" statement, because un-commenting it makes it all work again, but still cannot link to the individual tab from the outside.  When it is on, it seems like the ContactRE.php#Social does link, but only after typing it in, hitting enter, waiting and then hitting refresh.
4. Example 4- index.php You can see it is similar to Example 1, simply a different page to test the linking. It doesn't work.  The tab content just disappears.

For both Example 1, 2 and 4 you can see I tried to figure this out on my own before even hitting the forums in the "BottomInfo" class, where the sitemap will be located.  Links3 is the one I started with when I realized the system I thought would work, in Links2 and Links1 wasn't going to cut it. I simply took the links that constitute the tabs, removed styling through CSS and made the list.  Works for it's respective page, but not to link externally.

I've created a JSFiddle, for those that prefer it.  I am not very good at understanding a "hey, just add this and suddenly- magic!" followed by snippets of code, unless they come with great explanations.  Maybe one day, just not yet. http://jsfiddle.net/ANCannan/CfGHp/

Below is my working JS, but I cannot use a hash in the URL to link to the tabs externally

```
    <script type= "text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
  //  When user clicks on tab, this code will be executed
   $("#tabs li").click(function() {
  //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
   $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');

  //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
   $(this).addClass("active");

  //  Hide all tab content
   $(".tab_content").hide();

  //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
   var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

  //  Show the selected tab content
   $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

  //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
     return false;

  });});
  </script>
```

This is my Frankenstein JS attempt at making the tabs link-able by a hash in URL

```
       <script type= "text/javascript"> 
       $(document).ready(function(){
      //  When user clicks on tab, this code will be executed
       $("#tabs li").click(function() {
      //  First remove class "active" from currently active tab
       $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');

      //  Now add class "active" to the selected/clicked tab
       $(this).addClass("active");

     //  Hide all tab content
       $(".tab_content").hide();

    //  Here we get the href value of the selected tab
     var selected_tab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");

    //  Show the selected tab content
    $(selected_tab).fadeIn();

    //  At the end, we add return false so that the click on the link is not executed
     return false;
    });
if (window.location.hash !== '') {
    var $targetAnchor = $(document.location.hash);
    // Grab the ID of the .tab-content that the hash is referring to
    tabId = $targetAnchor.closest('.tab_content').attr('id');

    // Find the anchor element to "click", and click it
    $("#tabs li").find('a[href=#' + tabId + ']').click();

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $targetAnchor.offset().top
    });
    }


   $('a').not('.tabs li a').on('click', function(evt) {
     evt.preventDefault();
     var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
    $tabs = $("ul.tabs li");
    $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click');
      alert(attr('name'));
     alert( $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top );
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top
   });

 });

 $(function() {
     $('a.refresh').live("click", function() {
     location.reload();
   });
   });});
    </script>
```

This is my abbreviated HTML

```
<div class= "Centered" id="TextContent">
    <div id="tabs_container">
      <ul id="tabs">
      <li>
        <div class= "Centered" id="TextContent2">
          <div id="tabs_container2">
            <ul id="tabs2">
              <li class="active">
                <div class= "LinkText" id="TT1"> <a class="icon_accept" href="#Before">Before</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class= "LinkText" id="TT2"> <a class="icon_accept" href="#During">During</a></div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div class= "LinkText" id="TT3"> <a class="icon_accept" href="#After">After</a></div>
              </li>
            </ul><!---Ends ul id "tabs" container2-->
          </div><!---Ends "tabs_container2"-->
        </div><!---Ends "Centered Text Content2"-->
        </li>
       </ul><!---Ends ul id "tabs-->
     </div><!---Ends "tabs-container"-->

    <div id="tabs_content_container">
        <div id="Before" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">
         <img src="Images/before.png" class="alignLeft" alt="CMC and QA Icons"><p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt consectetur adipisicing elit,   duis aute irure dolor. In reprehenderit in voluptate quis nostrud   exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ullamco laboris nisi qui officia   deserunt lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur.</p><p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt consectetur adipisicing elit,   duis aute irure dolor. In reprehenderit in voluptate quis nostrud   exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ullamco laboris nisi qui officia   deserunt lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur.</p>
           </div><!---Ends Before container-->

             <div id="During" class="tab_content" style="display: block;">   
          <p>In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
           <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur.</p>
           <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt consectetur adipisicing elit,   duis aute irure dolor. In reprehenderit in voluptate quis nostrud   exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ullamco laboris nisi qui officia   deserunt lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
           <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur. 

       </div><!---Ends "During"-->

           <div id="After" class="tab_content">
             <img src="Images/after.png" class="alignRight" alt="CMC and QA Icons">

         <p> <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt consectetur adipisicing elit,   duis aute irure dolor. In reprehenderit in voluptate quis nostrud   exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ullamco laboris nisi qui officia   deserunt lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur.</p>
      <p>Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt consectetur adipisicing elit,   duis aute irure dolor. In reprehenderit in voluptate quis nostrud   exercitation eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Ullamco laboris nisi qui officia   deserunt lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. In reprehenderit in voluptate   cupidatat non proident, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
       <p>Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Consectetur   adipisicing elit, in reprehenderit in voluptate ut enim ad minim veniam.   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, quis nostrud exercitation velit esse cillum   dolore. In reprehenderit in voluptate excepteur sint occaecat eu fugiat   nulla pariatur.</p>
                    </div><!---Ends "After"-->
```

I've read through the following and tried to implement in various ways, though none worked.  I've even tried to apply some of the accordion thought structure, since people seem to ask the same question about accordions, but I am not good at applying it to the tabs.

#### related Questions on stackoverflow

- [link-to-an-anchor-within-jquery-tabbed-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10595351/link-to-an-anchor-within-jquery-tabbed-content)
- [unable-to-call-specific-content-from-an-external-file-inside-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024663/unable-to-call-specific-content-from-an-external-file-inside-jquery?rq=1)
- [use-one-jquery-code-for-all-tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244889/use-one-jquery-code-for-all-tabs)
- [how-to-link-directly-to-jquery-accordion-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333436/how-to-link-directly-to-jquery-accordion-tab)
- [link-to-open-jquery-accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588030/link-to-open-jquery-accordion?rq=1)
- [jquery-tabs-link-to-another-tab-from-inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11775008/jquery-tabs-link-to-another-tab-from-inside?rq=1)

JQuery's topic/link-to-tab-from-outside-tabs-div

---

Sorry for the lack of links, apparently I can only post 2.

**MAJOR UPDATE** Oct 19 1PM ET
I've not completely solved my problem, yet, but I can now link to a specific URL from outside the website (or type it in), however, if I am on the page the URL updates when I click on the link within the page or type it in manually, but it does not change the content until one clicks "refresh."
The page is http://certus.worldpath.net/crazy.html
Link directly to a tab by adding "#Email" to the end.
Thoughts?

I will greatly appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: Code would go much farther than more links would.

Comment: He can't, with only 6 rep, you aren't allowed to post more than 2 links.

Comment: In theory you could add a hash to the given urls, then when initializing the tabs, look for a hash value that matches a tab id, and if it exists, trigger the click event on said tab. Maybe someone will translate that into code for you.

Comment: Unfortunately the hash is what I was trying to do, mentioned in paragraphs 4 and 6. In all of my attempts, using the hash does not load the content.  The URL changes, but the content does not.  Sometimes, and only sometimes, refreshing the new URL will send the viewer to the correct tab.  That is why I have a suspicion it has something to do with the "//return false;" before the "if" statement.

Comment: I believe your html code is incomplete. If you take a look at my stripped [1] version you will find that the last div is not closed.

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/zrE9E/1/

Comment: Ah, yes. I see that. Thank you. Would that impact my page executing or refreshing?  I think I fixed that in http://certus.worldpath.net/crazy.html#Email, but will check.

Comment: Instead of alerts you can use console.log("foo") in Mozilla and in Chrome. For CSS and JavaScript trouble the chrome dev tools are a great help. Please take a look here if you want to learn more about the dev tools: http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: Could you please clarify why this question is not constructive?

It basically says: How to set up Tab + Content display with serveral links and fragment identifiers (anchor links / hash-links)?

I am willing to overhaul it completly to make it a better fit if this reopens it again.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: I second threeFourOneSixOneThree  Of course, I would.  I could not find this answer anywhere and finally found it through this forum.  I will readily admit I may not completely understand correct formatting for the question, but would learn a great deal seeing it structured properly, as I learned following people's answers to this question. This would make me a more valuable contributor in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A demo that uses jquery.tools for the tabs

As far as i understood your question this should match your problem:

- [Tab B-1](http://jsfiddle.net/Gingah/2TPxn/show/#B-1)
- [Tab B-3](http://jsfiddle.net/Gingah/2TPxn/show/#B-3)

### The solution with your code to your original question

- How to Link to tabbed content from an external link?
- solved

Please take a [look at the solution](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE9E/11/) ([#During](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE9E/11/show/#During), [#After](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE9E/11/show/#After))

```
    if (window.location.hash) {
        var wndHash = window.location.hash;
        var tab = wndHash + "Tab";
        // if hash exist on doc ready then remove class "active" from all tabs        
        $("#tabs li").removeClass('active');
        // show the tab content and make tab list item (li) active
        $(wndHash).fadeIn();            
        $(tab).parent().addClass("active");
        console.log(wndHash, $(wndHash), tab, $(tab));
    } else {
        // if no hash make the BeforeTab active
        $("#Before").fadeIn();            
        $("#BeforeTab").parent().addClass("active");
    }
```

#### Excursion using CSS3 selectors

Based on [Naman Goel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1752518/naman-goel) suggestion (see in this thread) i have set up a [basic css3 target selector demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wUFXG/1/show/#end):

```
 <h2>Table of contents</h2>
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#intro">intro</a>
     <li><a href="#end">the end</a>
 </ul>        
 <h2><a name="intro">CSS3 selectors and the :target pseudo class</a></h2>
<h2><a name="end">Look at me - i am the END-Anchor</a></h2>
```

And this css

```
h2 {font-size: 24px; font-weight: heavy; padding: 1em;}
*:target { color: red; font-size: 32px; }
```

Are the basic setup to change the css of the h2 heading if the url contains the corresponding anchor (either #intro or #end)

### How to change content of a tab with internal (anchor) links?

In your major update you write: "If I am on the page the URL updates when I click on the link within the page but it does not change the content"

In [your page](http://certus.worldpath.net/crazy.html) all tabs [(tab Email)](http://certus.worldpath.net/crazy.html#Email) are working fine and are loading their corresponding content. So i assume that you are talking about the links in the footer of the page crazy.html:

```
<div class="BottomInfo" id="A234">
    <div class="Links3">
        <a href="Contact.php">Contact</a>
        <ul id="Nottabs">
            <li class="Lactive">foo</li>
            <li><div class="LinkText" id="LinksTT2"> 
                    <a class="icon_accept" href="#Email">Email Us</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul><!---Ends ul id "Nottabs-->
    </div>
</div>
```

If you click on this link the content is not updated since  you do not have an event handler attached for the links in the footer.

#### No Event handler for links at footer

With [chrome devtools](http://paulirish.com/2011/a-re-introduction-to-the-chrome-developer-tools/) you can see that there are no event handlers attached to the links in the footer.

[image: No Event Handler for E-Mail Us link at footer(Screenshot in Chrome-Dev tools)].

In your javascript you add a click event for every DOM Node that matches this [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) `$("#tabs li")`. In your footer (`BottomInfo`) the list item does not match the same selector like the one in your tabs. Therefore nothing happens when you click on the links in the footer. If you add an event handler for the list items `$("#Nottabs li").click(...` and put the same code as in your tabs it should work.

```
$("#Nottabs li").click(function () {
   // similar to your tab solution 
   // you have to attach a click-event handler 
   // to the list item in your BottomInfo 
}
```

### Fully working demo with javascript and css 2

Please take a look at [the fully working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE9E/24/show/#After) with your code as a starting point.

Please let me know if this solves your problem

#### Minor update

I found a [demo for tabs using css3](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3ContentTabs/index.html). This is quite impressive.

Comment: Thank you @threeFourOneSIxOneThree, I will look into your answer. I have to spend time with it to understand what you did and how to apply it to what I am doing.

Comment: Thank you for your effort answering my question.  It helped me think through where the issue was.  I started a page, almost from scratch and realized I could apply some of your info in that page.  I was right. I struggled to apply the code you provided to what I posted, because there was so much difference in class names I couldn't keep it all straight. I'll continue looking through it and the links provided in the comments. Any thoughts why the page doesn't execute or refresh, as mentioned in my **Major Update**? That must be easier to solve?

Comment: Please see my update from today above.

Comment: This completely worked- I was over complicating it, renaming everything in my #Nottabs li function rather than simply pasting exactly what was in tabs.  Once I did that, it all worked, just like you said.  The Chrome devtools also helped.  I've always been a big Firebug person, but it did seem to have a few nuances that Firebug doesn't.  It all makes sense, now. Thank you so much.  Your explanation really goes above and beyond!

Comment: Glad i could help. Could you do me a favor. As you may have noticed 4 moderators have closed the question. To reopen it i overhauled your question which in my opinion fits your problem. Could you follow this link stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/859468 and see if my suggested edit matches your intended question and if this is the case update your question? My edit has been mostly rejected, but i believe it would help everyone if we could change your question so it better fits according to the faq Thanks a lot

Comment: I tried to do so, but am unable. Apparently I do not have enough points?  I do feel that your re-wording gets to the heart of the matter much faster than my original question and would encourage other reviewers to approve it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a MUCH simpler solution for you.
use the CSS3 property of :target for your tabbed interface.
Everything will just start working for you that way.

Also, you can use [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/) to polyfill it for older browsers.

basically you define different divs with the tabbed content.  and set it to display:none
And div:target { display:block; }

and the tab buttons can be simple links to #idnameofDiv

It's really quite easy. It should be perfect for you, PLUS NO javascript.

Comment: According to caniuse.com css 3 selectors are already fairly supported: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Comment: I made a tiny demo to show how css-3 and anchor links work togehter. Just click on the links at the top of the page to see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/wUFXG/1/show/#end

Comment: Hmmm... I will look into this further, but I don't think I need the :target CSS3 property to make it all work. I will have to read up on this.  I am trying very hard to not require separate code for IE, and have come pretty far in that attempt.  Unfortunately 15% of our users are IE 8 users (same percentage as FireFox), and 4.4% are IE7 and below. Internally, I am the only one with IE9 or above. Simply isn't my decision, unfortunately.

Comment: As I said Selectivizr can be used to polyfill it for and IE8 and lower. It's relatively lightweight as well. Still if it's not your decision, you can just try.