# Toggle Visibility - Show/Hide - Remain shown when toggled

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this piece of code which works great but, I would like the div to remain open if clicked on when the page is refreshed. ex. the user views a link and then returns to the previous page.
The link is an image and the page(div) is a menu of images.

```
<div id="block1-1">
    <a name="works"></a>
    <a href="#block1-1" onclick="toggle_visibility('block1-1');"><h2>works</h2></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function toggle_visibility(id){
       var e = document.getElementById(id);

       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? Also, if you want to persist changes on a reload, you need to store a variable somewhere. A cookie, a database, localstorage, etc.

Comment: You can use anchor links. Your problem is similar to [linking to tabbed content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964070/). The difference is if you want to support a use case where the surfer opens a div, closes the browser and reopens it. In this use case you have to use a cookie, or a database or localstorage.

Comment: ok,I believe a cookie would do the trick. Being this is a website it could remember the last state. What would the code look like? I am new to javascript and am struggling a bit. Thanks

Comment: There are so many jquery plugin to save data locally in browser. You can try [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/) . jStorage supports all major browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local Storage is probably the simplest solution (only works on some browsers).

Modify your function to include the local storage code:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block'){
      e.style.display = 'none';
      localStorage.setItem("show", false);
    }
    else{
      e.style.display = 'block';
      localStorage.setItem("show", true);
      localStorage.setItem("id", e);
    }
    };
```

Then you'd need to incorporate this:

```
window.onload=function(){
  if(localStorage.getItem("show")){
    var e = localStorage.getItem("id");
    e = document.getElementById("e");
    e.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe I am inputing the code right. But,The div no longer opens(shows) when I change it to the above code.

Comment: I messed up the brackets. I have edited my answer to fix the issue.

Comment: yes, that did fix the show/hide issue. But,unfortunately the divs remain closed on refresh and link back.

Comment: Ah, fix the second bit of code I have updated. The problem was we identified the ID without specifying what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give `display` style for the `div`

```
<div id="block1-1" style="display:block;">
```